# Cannot upload build without app clip to app store connect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I have previously uploaded a build with an app clip but now I have removed it. I have removed the files and references to the app clip in the xcode project and uploaded another build without the app clip to app store connect. However now it is saying that there is an error in which I cannot save the page with the build that does not have an app clip. The page on app store connect is still telling me to provide a picture and subtitle and URL for the app clip so I'm guessing that it doesn't think I have removed the app clip completely. I would like to upload the build without the app clip. Is there a way to accomplish this? Some help would be great:)

Edit:
The problem is solved by deleting the bundle identifier and creating a new one. Essentially I have created a new app that is completely the same as the old one, only with a different bundle ID. But is there a way to resolve this situation without having to change the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all deactivated Advanced app clip in App Store Connect

[image: screenshot]

Then from TestFlight expired all builds which contain App Clip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and resolved it without removing the app clips (which I want to submit for release). I had, during my wandering through the settings of the app changed the Release type from Public to Private.

To change it back to Public (you can't run App Clips without a public App Store app) go to Pricing and Availability, then scroll to the bottom and make sure Public is checked.
[image: Navigating to public or private availability setting]